# Set Variable using Format-Table and Out-String without extra lines

Tags: powershell

I'm currently trying to get a variable to hold just the name of a Get-ADUser output, but when I format everything out it still outputs with blank lines.

```
    $UserName = Read-Host "Username"
    $DisplayName = Get-Aduser $Username | Select-Object Name | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
```

I would expect the output for

```
    Write-Host "User: $DisplayName"
```

to just say "User: John Doe" but it comes out as

```
    User:

    John Doe
```

And leaves two more empty lines under John Doe. Is there a way to get the output I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're over complicating this a bit.  You want to `Select` the property of that object and only that property, so instead of trying to clean it up to display what you want here is the easiest and cleanest way.

```
$DisplayName = Get-Aduser $Username | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

This will work the same for other cmdlets as with object based output. You can also use dot notation to achieve the same thing.

```
$DisplayName = (Get-Aduser $Username).Name
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I've never seen that syntax before, but now I'll never forget. I promise I tried looking for this on Google for quite some time and found nothing on this. Thank you.